# Hibernate update causes collection to be deleted and re-inserted

Tags: java, mysql, hibernate, model-view-controller

I am facing this "logical error":

I have a `UserGroup` model related with the `SectionPermission` table in a `@ManyToMany` relation. The `UserGroup` model extends a `BaseModel @MappedSuperclass`.

**UserGroup class `@ManyToMany`:**

```
@ManyToMany(fetch = FetchType.EAGER, cascade = CascadeType.PERSIST)
@JoinTable(name = "user_section_permission", joinColumns = {
    @JoinColumn(name = "id_user_group", nullable = false, updatable = false)},
        inverseJoinColumns = {
            @JoinColumn(name = "id_section_permission",
                    nullable = false, updatable = false)})
public List<SectionPermission> getSectionPermissions() {
    return sectionPermissions;
}
```

**SectionPermissionClass `@ManyToMany`:**

```
@ManyToMany(fetch = FetchType.LAZY, cascade = CascadeType.MERGE)
@JoinTable(name = "user_section_permission", joinColumns = {
    @JoinColumn(name = "id_section_permission", nullable = false, updatable = false)},
        inverseJoinColumns = {
            @JoinColumn(name = "id_user_group",
                    nullable = false, updatable = false)})
public List<UserGroup> getUserGroups() {
    return userGroups;
}
```

When I perform an update on this model updating the `user_section_permission` table Hibernate deletes the collection and re-inserts every single record!

I've found this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2649145/hibernate-insert-to-a-collection-causes-a-delete-then-all-the-items-in-the-colle) and seems an equals/hashcode problem. This is the code I implement in every model of my application:

**BaseModel class**

```
@Override
public int hashCode() {
    int hash = 0;
    hash += (getId() != null ? getId().hashCode() : 0);
    return hash;
}

@Override
public boolean equals(Object object) {
    if (!(object instanceof BaseModel)) {
        return false;
    }

    BaseModel other = (BaseModel) object;
    return !((getId() == null && other.getId() != null) || (getId() != null && !getId().equals(other.getId())));
}
```

**ANY OTHER CLASS**

```
@Override
public int hashCode() {
    int hash = 0;
    hash += (getId() != null ? getId().hashCode() : 0);
    return hash;
}

@Override
public boolean equals(Object object) {
    if(!(object instanceof UserGroup)) {
        return false;
    }

    Model other = (Model) object;
    return !((getId() == null && other.getId() != null) || (getId() != null && !getId().equals(other.getId())));
}
```

Any suggestion of what am I doing wrong?

Comment: how could the ID be null?

Comment: When I istantiate a model the ID is null, only on save is populated

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is that you're basing the equals and hashcode on ids, and I assume the ids are auto-generated. This combination doesn't work with any ORM I know.

I would suggest you to read this [wiki page](https://developer.jboss.org/wiki/EqualsAndHashCode) that explains ho Hibernate uses equals and hashcode and what to be careful about.

One of the solutions is for you to provide the IDs (maybe using a UUID) or write the equals/hashcode to be based on *business equality* rather than database equality.

Most of the time, you don't need to override equals/hashcode... and you're using `List`s, so probably you don't need them at all.