# Hibernate deleting all and re-inserting all including new items in collections whenever adding new items for ManyToMany relationship

Tags: hibernate

I have two class A and B, and class A has member variable lets say bCollection which holds collection of B which is HashSet but class B doesn't hold class A as member variable. In hibernate i have defined @ManyToMany relationship for member variable bCollection and i have also configured hascode and equals method properly in class A and B.

Now the problem is whenever i am adding B in bCollection, it first delete all the B's from DB and then reinserts the new ones. I am unable to understand why it just don't add the new B by only inserting new B as its a big problem if A has big collection of B.

Note - Its intentional to have just one way relationship

Reference Code and Console Output -

```
@Entity
@Table(name=“A”)
public class A {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy=GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private int id;
    @ManyToMany
    @JoinTable(name=“A_B”,joinColumns=@JoinColumn(name=“B_id"))
    private Collection<B> bCollection = new HashSet<B>();
}

@Entity
@Table(name=“B”)
public class B {
      @Id
      @GeneratedValue(strategy=GenerationType.IDENTITY)
      private int id;
}
```

Console output - When adding a new B into bCollection and then updating A

```
 Hibernate: delete from A_B where A_id=?
 Hibernate: insert into A_B (A_id, B_id) values (?, ?)
 Hibernate: insert into A_B (A_id, B_id) values (?, ?)
 Hibernate: insert into A_B (A_id, B_id) values (?, ?)
```

Comment: Do you have the same behavior if you use a set instead of a collection? I cannot explain it from any documentation, but I have seen this behavior in both collections and lists, but a set behaves how I expect it to.

Comment: Nathan, You are right. After changing Collection to Set, its not deleting and directly insert the new items. That's strange. Anyone know the reason and is there any option to get it work via Collection

Answer (score 0):

@Nathan Kummer is correct, using `Set` instead of `Collection` would probably fix it. This was [StackOverflowed here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2649145/hibernate-insert-to-a-collection-causes-a-delete-then-all-the-items-in-the-colle) before, and also [bloged here](http://lkumarjain.blogspot.cz/2013/07/why-hibernate-does-delete-all-entries.html).

---

### Original answer

You might need this as well.

First, `joinColumns` should point to the *entity owning the association*. And second you need to define `inverseJoinColumns` - *the inverse side of the association* as well:

```
@JoinTable(name="A_B", 
   joinColumns = @JoinColumn(name="A_id"),
   inverseJoinColumns = @JoinColumn(name = "B_id"))
private Collection<B> bCollection = new HashSet<B>();
```