# Spring-data, read only field mapped by View

Tags: java, spring, spring-data-jpa

I am using Spring-data, and I want to replace a collections mapped by table, by using View. But when I save EntityParent contains this collection, I can see it try to insert a data in my View :

org.springframework.dao.InvalidDataAccessResourceUsageException: could not execute batch; SQL [insert into view_data1_data2 (data1_id_fk, data2_id_fk) values (?, ?)];

Caused by: java.sql.BatchUpdateException: ORA-01779: cannot modify a column which maps to a non key-preserved table

And when I try to update EntityParent, I has this error :

org.springframework.dao.InvalidDataAccessResourceUsageException: could not execute batch; delete from view_data1_data2 where data1_id_fk=?

Caused by: java.sql.BatchUpdateException: ORA-01752: cannot delete from view without exactly one key-preserved table.

I wondering, if it's possible to not persist any data in my View when i save or update ?

I tried to set updatable and insertable to false, at annotation JoinColumn or Column, but it's doesn't work. I tried @ReadOnlyProperty, and it seems the same result.

```
class EntityParent {
...
    @ManyToMany(fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
    @JoinTable(name = "view_data1_data2",
            joinColumns = {@JoinColumn(name = "data1_id_fk", referencedColumnName = "id", updatable = false, insertable = false)},
            inverseJoinColumns = {@JoinColumn(name = "data2_id_fk", referencedColumnName = "id", updatable = false, insertable = false)})
    private List<MyData> myDatas;
...
}
```

Comment: If you know that table is a view, then why do you try to change the content of that collection? If you don't add/delete entities, then JPA won't try to modify the table.

Comment: Do you actually modify the collection? See also here for issue when Hibernate deletes and reinserts all records in many-to-many: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2649145/hibernate-insert-to-a-collection-causes-a-delete-then-all-the-items-in-the-colle

Comment: Thank you @alan-hay, your link resolve my problem, I change my Collection "List" to "Set" and it work.