# JPA , many-to-many relation, deleting all previous relations and entering the new relations

Tags: java, jakarta-ee, jpa, ejb-3.0, jpa-2.0

here i am trying out many-to-many relationship in JPA, I'v created tables "tblcourse" and "tblStudent", a student can register to many courses,

```
create table tblcourse(
    id integer primary key,
    name varchar(100),
    duration integer
);

create table tblcourseStudent(
    studentid integer references tblstudent(studentId),
    courseId integer references tblcourse(id),
    constraint pk_composit_cs primary key(studentid,courseId)
)

Create table tblStudent(
    studentId integer primary key,
    ……..
    ….
);
```

The JPA representation of the above relation is as follows,
this is the code for StudentEntity.java,

```
@Entity
@Table(name="TBLSTUDENT")
public class StudentEntity implements Serializable{

private static final long serialVersionUID = 100034222342L;

@Id
@Column(name="STUDENTID")
private Integer studentId;

@Column(name="STUDENTNAME")
private String studentName;

@Column(name="CONTACTNO")
private String contactNumber;

@Embedded
private StudentAddress address;

@ManyToOne(fetch=FetchType.LAZY)
@JoinColumn(name="DEPTID")
private DeptEntity deptEntity;

@ManyToMany(fetch=FetchType.LAZY)
@JoinTable(name="tblcourseStudent",
            joinColumns=@JoinColumn(name="studentid"),
            inverseJoinColumns=@JoinColumn(name="courseId"))
    private List<CourseEntity> courseList;  
....
.....
.....
}
```

this the code for CourseEntity.java,

```
@Entity
@Table(name="TBLCOURSE")
public class CourseEntity implements Serializable{

        public CourseEntity(){

        }

    public CourseEntity(Integer courseId,String courseName,Integer courseDuration){
        this.courseId = courseId;
        this.courseName = courseName;
        this.courseDuration = courseDuration;
    }

    /**
     * 
     */
    private static final long serialVersionUID = -2192479237310864341L;

    @Id
    @Column(name="ID")
    private Integer courseId;

    @Column(name="NAME")
    private String courseName;

    @Column(name="DURATION")
    private Integer courseDuration;

    @ManyToMany(fetch=FetchType.LAZY)
    @JoinTable(name="tblcourseStudent",
                joinColumns=@JoinColumn(name="courseId"),
                inverseJoinColumns=@JoinColumn(name="studentid"))
    private List<StudentEntity> studentList;
    .........
}
```

Now, when i try to insert courses throught StudentEntity.java,
the SQL queries fired at backend are

```
delete 
    from
        tblcourseStudent 
    where
        studentid=?

insert 
    into
        tblcourseStudent
        (studentid, courseId) 
    values
        (?, ?)

insert 
    into
        tblcourseStudent
        (studentid, courseId) 
    values
        (?, ?)
```

And, when i try to insert students throught CourseEntity.java,
the SQL queries fired are as follows,

```
delete 
    from
        tblcourseStudent 
    where
        courseId=?

insert 
    into
        tblcourseStudent
        (courseId, studentid) 
    values
        (?, ?)
```

in both of my case, the records are deleted and than the new mapping is inserted.
So if i am inserting Courses for a student, first all the previouse courses for the student will be deleted from the third table, and the new courses will be entered,

So, my question is, if i don't want to delete old courses and add the new courses for the student how can i achieve, i.e i want to retain the old relationship,

Weather i have to achieve this programatically,
or i have change the annotation,
Waiting for the reply

This the code written in StudentServiceBean.java and the method "mapStudentToCourses" gets called when we map a single student to multiple Courses

```
@Stateless
@TransactionManagement(TransactionManagementType.CONTAINER)
public class StudentServiceBean implements StudentService{


@PersistenceContext(unitName="forPractise")
private EntityManager entityMgr;

@Resource
private SessionContext sessionContext;

@EJB
private DeptService deptService;
..........
......
...

@Override
@TransactionAttribute(TransactionAttributeType.REQUIRED)
public void mapStudentToCourses(Integer studentId,String courseIdList) throws Exception{
    List<CourseEntity> courseList = null;
    StudentEntity studentEntity  = null;
    TypedQuery<CourseEntity> courseQuery = null;        
    String query = "select c from CourseEntity c where c.courseId in ("+courseIdList+")";
    try{
        courseQuery = entityMgr.createQuery(query,CourseEntity.class);
        courseList =  courseQuery.getResultList();
        studentEntity = entityMgr.find(StudentEntity.class, studentId);
        studentEntity.setCourseList(courseList);
        entityMgr.merge(studentEntity);        
    }catch(Exception e){
        sessionContext.setRollbackOnly();
        throw e;
    }
}
```

This is the code when one Course is mapped to multiple students, its CourseServiceBean.java

```
@Stateless
@TransactionManagement(TransactionManagementType.CONTAINER)
public class CourseServiceBean implements CourseService{

@PersistenceContext(name="forPractise")
private EntityManager em;

@Resource
private SessionContext sessionCtx;

private Map<Integer, String> durationCode = null;

@EJB
private StudentService studentService;
........
......
...

@Override
@TransactionAttribute(TransactionAttributeType.REQUIRED)
public void mapCourseToStudents(Integer courseId,String studentIdList) throws Exception{
    List<StudentEntity> studentEntityList = null;
    TypedQuery<StudentEntity> studentQuery = null;
    String query = "select s from StudentEntity s where s.studentId IN ("+studentIdList+")";
    CourseEntity courseEntity = null;
    try{
        studentQuery = em.createQuery(query, StudentEntity.class);
        studentEntityList = studentQuery.getResultList();
        courseEntity = em.find(CourseEntity.class,courseId);
        courseEntity.setStudentList(studentEntityList);
        em.merge(courseEntity);
    }catch(Exception e){
        sessionCtx.setRollbackOnly();
        throw e;
    }
}
}
```

this my persistence.xml file,

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<persistence xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/persistence"
             xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
             xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/persistence http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/persistence/persistence_2_0.xsd"
             version="2.0">
    <persistence-unit name="forPractise" transaction-type="JTA">
        <provider>org.hibernate.ejb.HibernatePersistence</provider>
        <jta-data-source>jdbc/app</jta-data-source>
        <class>com.entity.StudentEntity</class>
        <class>com.entity.DeptEntity</class>
        <class>com.entity.CourseEntity</class>      
        <properties>
            <property name="hibernate.dialect"  value="org.hibernate.dialect.DerbyDialect"  />
            <property name="hibernate.show_sql" value="true" />
            <property name="hibernate.format_sql" value="true" />                           
        </properties>
    </persistence-unit>
</persistence>
```

waiting for the reply....

Comment: Can you post the config file persistence.xml?

Comment: Can you post the code you're running to make the insertions?

Comment: Added the code for save method, and also added persistence.xml

Comment: Possible duplicate of [JPA update many-to-many deleting records](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3504371/jpa-update-many-to-many-deleting-records)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I might be wrong but I think this is normal that when you're making your insertions, Hibernate firsts deletes all the records from the associated table.

That's the reason : when working with x-to-many association (basically, associations that are mapped through a Collection), Hibernate's persistence context will perfom the dirty checkings based on the Collection's identifier.

Let's take the mapCourseToStudents() method from your CourseServiceBean class :

```
    ...
    studentQuery = em.createQuery(query, StudentEntity.class);
    studentEntityList = studentQuery.getResultList();
    courseEntity = em.find(CourseEntity.class,courseId);
    courseEntity.setStudentList(studentEntityList); // replacing the previous Collection by the one you retrieved by querying the DB !!! 
    em.merge(courseEntity);
    ...
```

If you really want to avoid Hibernate executing the delete statement first, you should add/remove items to the Collection instead of assigning a new Collection and configure in the mapping data the operations that you want to cascade.

Answer (score 0):

Add new courses to the existing list:

```
Collection<Student> moreStudents = ...

course = em.find(CourseEntity.class,courseId);
course.getStudentList().addAll(moreStudents);
```

Comment: (Regarding naming, consider removing unnecessary clutter like *List, *Entity, etc in your class and variable names. Eg: Student, Course, Participation, course.getStudents(). Less to write and read :-)

Answer (score 0):

I didn't overwrite the whole relationship list, and instead I add new entity to the original list. But, Hibernate still delete all my previous relationships.

According to this article: 
https://vladmihalcea.com/the-best-way-to-use-the-manytomany-annotation-with-jpa-and-hibernate/

This seems to be the current behaviour of Hibernate, and if we don't want that, we have to first correctly implement our entity's `hashCode()` and `equals()` methods, and use Set to model the ManyToMany relationship.

Answer (score 0):

I faced similar challange .
I am providing the similar kind of scenario hope it may be helpful to some people.

i am taking Product and Order to explain the issue and using uni-directional manyToMany mapping

```
@Entity
@Table(name="Product")
public class Product {

    @Id
    @Column(name = "id")
    private Long id;

    
    @Column(name = "product")
    private String product;

    @ManyToMany(cascade = CascadeType.PERSIST,fetch= FetchType.EAGER)
    @JoinTable(name = "product_order_mapping", joinColumns = { @JoinColumn(name = "product_id") }, inverseJoinColumns = {
            @JoinColumn(name = "order_id") })
    @JsonProperty("orders")
    private Set<Order> orders =new HashSet<Order>();

    //setters and getters


}

@Table(name="Order")
public class Order {

    @Id
    @Column(name = "id")
    private Long id;
        
    @Column(name = "order")
    private String order;

    //setters and getters
    //equals and hashcode

}
```

## Implementation Logic

productList and OrderFunctions are some list with list of products and orders details

```
for (Product pEntity : productList) {

OrderFunctions = this.getAllLineFunctions(product.getId(), cmEntity.getId())
                        .getBody();
Set<Order> oList = new HashSet<>();

for (OrderFunction orderFn : OrderFunctions) {
Order orderEntity = new Order();
orderEntity.setId(lfs.getOrderFunction_id());
orderEntity.setStageGroup(lfs.getOrderFunctionOrder());
oList.add(sgEntity);
}

orderRepository.saveAll(oList);
pEntity.setOrders(oList);
productRepository.save(pEntity);
}
}
```

## To understand duplicacy mapping let us take an example

Suppose Product is under a Company
Now a Company has multiple Product
And Product has Multiple Order

Now Let us take a practical example for storing data in tables

set1-->
company with id c1 has Product with id p1,p2,p3
product p1 has order o1,o2,o3
product p2 has order o1,o2
product p3 has order o2,o3,o4

set2-->
company with id c2 has Product with id p1,p3
product p1 has order o1,o2
product p3 has order o2

Now when save set1 table product_order_mapping looks like

```
product_id  order_id
---------------------
   p1         o1
   p1         o2
   p1         o3
   p2         o1
   p2         o2
   p3         o2
   p3         o3
   p3         o4
```

But when save set2 after set1 table product_order_mapping will look like

```
product_id  order_id
---------------------
   p1         o1
   p1         o2
   p2         o1
   p2         o2
   p3         o2
```

We can see the difference before saving set2 and after saving set2
mappings p1->o3 , p3->o3 and p3->o4 are lost

## Reason for losing mapping

when we tried to store set2 we tried to override the duplicate entry like p1->o1,p1->o2 which are allready available
in the mapping table
So what happened is before adding these duplicate entry all mappings related to p1 are removed and then
p1->o1,p1->o2 got added

And so we lost some previous entry

## Solution

Avoid adding duplicate entry from set2 like p1->o1,p1->o2 as they are already present in mapping table

```
for (Company cEntity : companyList) {
for (Product pEntity : productList) {

OrderFunctions = this.getAllOrderFunctions(cEntity.getId(), pEntity.getId());
                        
Set<Order> oList = new HashSet<>();

for (OrderFunction orderFn : OrderFunctions) {
Order orderEntity = new Order();
orderEntity.setId(lfs.getOrderFunction_id());
orderEntity.setStageGroup(lfs.getOrderFunctionOrder());
oList.add(sgEntity);
}

Set<Order> collectSG = pEntity.getOrders().stream().filter(o->oList.contains(o)).collect(Collectors.toSet());
oList.removeAll(collectSG);
if(oList.size()>0) {
orderRepository.saveAll(oList);
                
pEntity.setOrders(oList);
productRepository.save(pEntity);
}
}
}
}
```