# Spring boot, sub entity, records automatically deleted without save and update

Tags: java, hibernate, spring-boot, spring-data-jpa, spring-data

Issue:
Records are deleting automatically from sub entity without firing any save/update statement. Need to prevent that deletion.

Below is entity:

```
@Entity
@Table(name="siteuser")
public class User implements UserDetails {

    @ManyToMany(fetch = FetchType.LAZY, cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
    @JoinTable(name = "siteuser_subcategory",
    joinColumns = {@JoinColumn(name = "userId") },
    inverseJoinColumns = { @JoinColumn(name = "subCategoryId") })
    @JsonIgnore
    private List<SubCategory> subcategoryList = new ArrayList<SubCategory>();

}
```

Here in `cascade` I tried all possible options `DETACH,MERGE,PERSIST,REFRESH,REMOVE` but no solution.

Also there is no any physical class entity for table 'siteuser_subcategory'. That table managed by only this above code.

I tried many ways to solve this issue as explained in this link
[Why does Hibernate try to delete when I try to update/insert?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/179259/4748798)

Please guide for better solutions or anyway by try it.

Thank you in advance.

Comment: Some context is required.You must be doing *something*!